# Finding peak in an array

Tags: python

I'm completely new to Python, thus the question.
I'm trying to solve a standard interview question, which is finding a peak in an array
A peak is defined as a number which is greater than it's left and right neighbor. I'm trying to find the largest such peak.

This is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def main():
    arr = [7, 12, 13, 8, 2, 16, 24, 11, 5, 1]
    num = find_peak(arr)
    print(num)

def find_peak(arr):
    return find_peak(arr, 0, len(arr))

def find_peak(arr, start, stop):

    mid = (start + stop)/2

    if(arr[mid] > arr[mid-1] and arr[mid] > arr[mid+1]):
        return arr[mid]
    elif (arr[mid] < arr[mid -1]):
        find_peak(arr, 0, mid-1)
    elif (arr[mid] < arr[mid+1]):
        find_peak(arr, mid+1, stop)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the error that I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peak.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "peak.py", line 5, in main
    num = find_peak(arr)
TypeError: find_peak() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'start' and 'stop'
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Don't understand the down vote. If everyone knew everything, what's the point of stackoverflow

Answer (score 4):

You've got two function definitions for `find_peak`, one with one argument `arr` and the other with three arguments `arr`, `start`, and `stop`. The second one overwrites the first one.

Use two different names for two different functions

Comment: Does that mean I can't do function overloading in python

Comment: That's what it means.

Comment: Once you've changed the function definition, you lose access to the original, which is garbage collected

Comment: So private helper functions in python need to have names separate from the caller functions, right?

Comment: @Zeus yes. You could define the second one (with three arguments) as `_find_peak`, or supply optional arguments with `def find_peak(arr, start=0, stop=None)` (and a bit more logic in the function

Comment: @Zeus: If you want to overload a function in Python based on the number of arguments, the usual way would be to define optional arguments. `*args` arguments also work. If you want to overload a function in Python based on argument types, that's mostly unsupported due to the dynamic nature of python, though [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) can get you some of that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling this:

```
num = find_peak(arr)
```

But `find_peak` takes 3 arguments, as the error states. You have only supplied one.

Unlike C++ or other languages, you cannot have a function with the same name that takes different arguments (also known as function overloading). You can, however, define optional arguments in the function declaration.

Comment: Well there's a find_peak with one argument also.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    arr = [7, 12, 13, 8, 2, 16, 24, 11, 5, 1]
    num = find_peak(arr)
    print(num)

def find_peak(arr):
    return find_peaks(arr, 0, len(arr))

def find_peaks(arr, start, stop):

    mid = (start + stop)/2

    if(arr[mid] > arr[mid-1] and arr[mid] > arr[mid+1]):
        return arr[mid]
    elif (arr[mid] < arr[mid -1]):
        find_peaks(arr, 0, mid-1)
    elif (arr[mid] < arr[mid+1]):
        find_peaks(arr, mid+1, stop)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Overloading is not allowed in Python, my suggestion is to use default values instead of two functions

```
def find_peak(arr, start = 0, stop = 0):
    if stop == 0:
        stop = len(arr)

    mid = (start + stop)/2

    if(arr[mid] > arr[mid-1] and arr[mid] > arr[mid+1]):
        return arr[mid]
    elif (arr[mid] < arr[mid -1]):
        find_peak(arr, 0, mid-1)
    elif (arr[mid] < arr[mid+1]):
        find_peak(arr, mid+1, stop)
```